# How to add all prices in this ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, double

On now my Java program will give me list of all user input in [] these brackets.
But what I want is to give me total all prices as noramally with out any brackets.

Please help me how do i do this?

```
public static void XalwoAmounts(ArrayList<Double> price){
for (int i = 0;  i<price.size(); i++){

    price.get(i);
    }
System.out.println("All Totals are : "+ price);
```

Comment: make a new var and sum in same loop the prices to it

Comment: I did same already and nothing have changed

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 Stream API based solution

`double sum  = price.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();`

You can update your method to

```
public static void XalwoAmounts(ArrayList<Double> price) {
        double sum = price.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
        System.out.println("All Totals are : " + sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Collector, summingDouble:

```
double sum = price.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(f -> f));
```

Comment: `Collectors.summingDouble` is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your, loop isn't actually doing anything. Every time you loop through it, you get a value from `price`, but never assign it to anything. Then you directly print out `price`, instead of the values contained in `price`. Printing the `ArrayList` directly is the cause of the output you're getting (Eg: `[12.2, 46.9]`) To print out the sum of the *values*, try this:

```
    double totalPrices = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0;  i < price.size(); i++){

        totalPrices += price.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println("All Totals are: " + totalPrices);
```

Comment: Can you please explain the downvote?

Comment: I sure can't as your answer is correct. 1+ (although the question is weak -- surely this has been asked many times before)

Comment: Excellent this is well done.